# Scrape data from Infinite scrolling using scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I'm new to python and scrapy.

I want to scrap data from website.

The web site uses AJAX for scrolling.

The get request url is as below.

```
http://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=Mumbai&search=Chemical+Dealers&where=&catid=944&psearch=&prid=&page=2&SID=&mntypgrp=0&toknbkt=&bookDate=
```

Please help me how I can use scrapy or any other python libraries

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this AJAX request expects a correct `Referer` header, which is just a url of the current page. You can simply set the header when creating the request:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # e.g. http://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Dentists/ct-385543
    my_headers = {'Referer': response.url}
    yield Request("ajax_request_url",
                  headers=my_headers,
                  callback=self.parse_ajax)

def parse_ajax(self, response):
    # results should be here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will try and let you know

Comment: I have tried the code and also try to scrap  data but getting the top 10 records only but I want to scrap the data from all the pages.

Comment: @JT28 you just need to increment `page` url parameter. i.e. this part of the url `&page=2` for other pages untill you get no results, that probably means you're past last page.

Comment: So in thihs case my response url  is `http://www.justdial.com/functions/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&act=pagination&city=Mumbai&search=Chemical+Dealers&where=&catid=944&psearch=&prid=&page=2&SID=&mntypgrp=0&toknbkt=&bookDate=
`  right?..! Because in `url=    # e.g. http://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Dentists/ct-385543
` I can't directly put or find `&page` option

Comment: @JT28 Yeah you need to modify response.url not the Referer header. You can use something like `next_url = re.sub('page=\d+','page={}'.format(next_page), response.url)` where `next_page = int(re.findall('page=(\d+)', response.url)[0]) + 1` or something like that, you get the idea :)

Comment: I'm going to post the code so please help me where and what i'm doing wrong